# Node.js Express - Get http protocol text for request

Tags: node.js, express, http

In node.js express, if I get a request with an undefined body I would like to log what the http protocol text was so that I can figure out what went wrong. I don't want to flood my logs with every single request made to the server just the one that comes up undefined.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by http protocol text?  Only some requests are supposed to have a body.  For example, a GET does not have a body.

Comment: Please rephrase the question!